# How can i duplicate a bunch of records in mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, records

How can I duplicate a bunch of records in mySQL?

I have records like this:

```
ID - name - year
-----------------
1 jasmine - 1999
2 peter   - 1999
3 fleur   - 1999
```

How can I duplicate all the names with `WHERE year='1999'` to a new row with a new year?

```
ID - name - year
-----------------
1 jasmine - 1999
2 peter   - 1999
3 fleur   - 1999
4 jasmine - 2000
5 peter   - 2000
6 fleur   - 2000
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Probably worth mentioning the concept of Normalisation here, to see if what you're asking for is really a good thing. A lot of the documentation on the web is a bit dry and technical, but basically "don't repeat yourself".

Answer (score 4):

```
INSERT INTO mytable (name, year)
SELECT (name, 2000) FROM mytable WHERE year = 1999;
```

Comment: You mean:

INSERT INTO mytable (name, 2000)
SELECT (name, year) FROM mytable WHERE year = 1999;

Am i right?

Comment: @AarClay: No, I mean exactly what I said :)  The first set of parentheses identify the fields into which the selected data are inserted.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this pls. In place of `2000` you can use as you wish.

```
INSERT INTO duplicate_entry (name, year) 
SELECT name, '2000' FROM duplicate_entry where year='1999'
```

Best of luck.